# Copy Elements (Select and Imput) in a Cell TD

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery, I need help on copying the Select, and Input boxes, but not the first text "Delete". So, let me explain.

I have this table below, and we going to focus on the rows two.

```
<table id="tableBucket" align="center" width="95%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" value="Add">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="r1" style="display:block">
        <td>
            <a href="#" onClick="$(this).removeRow();">Delete</a>
            <select name="ddlBucket_1_1" id="ddlBucket_1_1">
                <option value="a">a</option>
                <option value="b">b</option>
                <option value="c">c</option>                
            </select>

            <select id="ddlOp_1_1" name="ddlOp_1_1">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="=">equal</option>
                <option value=">">greater</option>
                <option value=">=">greater or equal</option>
                <option value="<">less</option>
                <option value="=<">less or equal</option>
            </select>

            $<input type="text" id="BucketAmount_1_1" name="BucketAmount_1_1" size="12" />

            <select class="xor" id="ddlAndOR_1_1" name="ddlAndOR_1_1">
                <option value="And">And</option>
                <option value="Or">Or</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr><br />
</table>
```

When a SELECT dropdown with class="xor" selected, it will call this function below to copy the elements inside the cell to the same cell.

```
var myTbl = $('#tableBucket'), count = 1;
    myTbl.eq(0).on('change', 'td select.xor', function(){

        count += 1;
        var tds = [];
        var lastTr = $(this).closest("tr");
        //alert(lastTr);
        lastTr.find("td:eq(0)").each(function() {
            var idArr = ($(this).find('select, input').attr('id')).split('_');
            var newID = idArr[0] + '_' + idArr[1] + '_' + (count);
            alert("newID: " + newID);
            tds.push($(this).clone().find('select, input').attr('id', newID).prop('name', newID).end());
            alert(tds);
        })
        lastTr.append(tds);
    });
```

This function copy ALL in the cell, meaning it also copy the DELETE link ( tag), and Select, and Text.  What I like to do is just copy starting from SELECT (ddlBucket_1_1) .... to the rest of elements (ddlAndOR_1_1).  I also like to put the tag `<BR />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`  before all the copied elements like below output after copied.

```
<table id="tableBucket" align="center" width="95%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" value="Add">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="r1" style="display:block">
        <td>
            <a href="#" onClick="$(this).removeRow();">Delete</a>
            <select name="ddlBucket_1_1" id="ddlBucket_1_1">
                <option value="a">a</option>
                <option value="b">b</option>
                <option value="c">c</option>                
            </select>

            <select id="ddlOp_1_1" name="ddlOp_1_1">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="=">equal</option>
                <option value=">">greater</option>
                <option value=">=">greater or equal</option>
                <option value="<">less</option>
                <option value="=<">less or equal</option>
            </select>

            $<input type="text" id="BucketAmount_1_1" name="BucketAmount_1_1" size="12" />

            <select class="xor" id="ddlAndOR_1_1" name="ddlAndOR_1_1">
                <option value="And">And</option>
                <option value="Or">Or</option>
            </select>

            <BR />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;             
            <select name="ddlBucket_1_1" id="ddlBucket_1_1">
                <option value="a">a</option>
                <option value="b">b</option>
                <option value="c">c</option>                
            </select>

            <select id="ddlOp_1_1" name="ddlOp_1_1">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="=">equal</option>
                <option value=">">greater</option>
                <option value=">=">greater or equal</option>
                <option value="<">less</option>
                <option value="=<">less or equal</option>
            </select>

            $<input type="text" id="BucketAmount_1_1" name="BucketAmount_1_1" size="12" />

            <select class="xor" id="ddlAndOR_1_1" name="ddlAndOR_1_1">
                <option value="And">And</option>
                <option value="Or">Or</option>
            </select>


        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 ways to do this but the easiest is probably to put everything but the `<a>` in a `<fieldset class="whatever">` and clone that with jquery's [`.clone()` method](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) like

```
var $formfields = $('fieldset.whatever').eq(0).clone();
$('#r1').append($formfields);
```

You can also skip all of the `<BR />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` hackery that way as well since fieldsets are block level elements.

EDIT: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gXM75/

Comment: Hi @Will, your answer provide the solution to copy whatever elements with in the Fieldset; however, it is exponentially copying the elements in the fieldset after 2nd time clone.  What I means is, 1st time clone it, it copy the first set, COOL!, next 2nd time, it clone 2 existing sets, so it become four sets now, and then 8 sets...so on.  Is there a way not to use fieldset, but just always copy the first 4 elements, starting from SELECT (so, Select, Select, Input, Select) ?  Thanks

Comment: Anyone? how to clone the elements 2-5 within the TD?